# Books Arranged on a Shelf: 5 must be to the left, and 2 must be to the right

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm told that there are five distinct books of category $A$, three distinct books of category $B$, and two of category $C$.

I'm then asked the following question:

> In how many ways can these books be arranged on a shelf if all five category $A$ books are on the left, and both category $C$ books are on the right?

In what follows is my attempt:

$$\underset{\_}{5}\underset{\_}{4}\underset{\_}{3}\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1}\underset{\_}{3}\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1}\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1}$$

Comment: I imagine you intend the product of all these numbers. If so, the answer is fine, except for the notation. I would prefer to say that the $5$ Cat A books can be arranged in $5!$ ways. For each of these ways the $3$ Cat B books can be arranged in $3!$ ways, and $\dots$. So the number of arrangements is $5!3!2!$.

Comment: So if I'm then asked how many ways can they be ordered so that each category is grouped together, then I would just use the fact that there are $3!$ variations on $ABC$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I would call $3!$ permutations of the letters A, B, and C.

Comment: And so there would then be exactly $5!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!$ variations for such demands, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Note that small changes in wording of a question can lead to large changes in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The categories must be arranged as follows:

$$ABC$$

Within $A$, there are $5!$ possible arrangements, within $B$ there are $3!$, and within $C$ there are $2!$. Using the rule of product, the total number of configurations allowable on the bookshelf is:

$$5!\cdot3!\cdot2!$$